# No route matches [GET] "/public/templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

In a rails project, I put my template in `public` folder. But when I want render the pages, I get below error for each css and css aren't load:

```
No route matches [GET] "/public/templates/assets/css/bootstrap.css"
```

I have below directory in public folder:

```
public/templates/assets/css
```

I set `config.serve_static_assets = true`, But the problem doesn't solve.

`server log:`

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/css/bootstrap.css
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `c
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `ca
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: I read this page, but not found my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should have some typos in your template:

`/public/templates/assetes/css/bootstrap.css` should really be `/public/templates/assets/css/bootstrap.css`.

Comment: Does that solve you problem? From you errors, I see that you may have some typos such as `assetes` should really be `assets`. And check whether you put `templates` before the url?

Comment: Please double check. Your `server log` shows `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assetes/css/bootstrap.css`. That means you may have mistakenly put `/assetes/css/bootstrap.css` somewhere in your code, but it should really be `/templates/assets/css/bootstrap.css`.

Comment: I checked it, it's write.